# Pinia action not updating state

Tags: vue.js, pinia

When I call the login action in the login component I get the err Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'user'). Why is user undefined when its defined in the state? Below is my Pinia store code

```
import {defineStore} from "pinia";
import axios from "axios";
import router from "@/router";
import {createToaster} from "@meforma/vue-toaster";

const toaster = createToaster({ position: "top-right"});

export const useStore = defineStore("main", {
    state: () => ({
        user: {},
        token: null
    }),
    actions: {
        login (email, password) {
            axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', {
                email: email,
                password: password
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    const user = response.data.data.user
                    const token = response.data.data.access_token

                    // update pinia state
                    this.user = user
                    this.token = token
                    // store user details and jwt in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
                    localStorage.setItem('token', token)
                    toaster.success(response.data.message)
                    // redirect to previous url or default to home page
                    router.push('/dashboard/home')
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                    //toaster.error(error.response.data.message)
                })
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Haven't used pinia but it looks like your use of `this.user = user` may be the problem. `this` there is probably not the pinia instance. You could do something like `const self=this;` before the axios call and use `self.user` inside your then callback function OR you could use the arrow notation for the callback function which will mean `this` should be the pinia instance. (same goes for token too)

Comment: @ChiragRavindra Thanx a lot this worked for me. `this` was an instance of Axios and not of Pinia.